# ASP.NET MVC - Working with View Models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am using a View Model for some operations (i.e. a model which is not directly contained within a database - instead of a data model).  Are there any resources out there for the best practices associated with using these?  For instance - if I have an Edit action in the controller - how will the view model know which data model(s) it corresponds with?  Should I keep a reference to the data model inside of the view model?

Comment: Usually you have a `@model YourModelType` directive in your view. Is this a kind of reference you think of?

Comment: William, if you search for ViewModels on SO, you'll see aplenty. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the 'best' practice is to craft your viewmodel with the data you need for your view - simple as that, more or less.  Sometimes this can contain data from more than one table, database, or even totally disparate data sources.  But if your view needs it, then you can put it into your view model.

"how will the view model know which data model(s) it corresponds with? Should I keep a reference to the data model inside of the view model?"

Well, presumably, if you put it together, you should know what data is what and how to unpack it again and save it or whatever you need to do if/when it comes back right?  You can build your viewmodel carefully to minimize any possible confusion...

VM's can be dead simple small objects, or big, complex ones with all kinds of things contained in them - depending on what you need of course.